# How to pass arguments to a class extension component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to extend a component as such:

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
...
}

export default withKeycloak(LoginPage);
```

However the example does it like this:

```
const LoginPage = ({ keycloak, keycloakInitialized }) => {
```

I'm not sure if this is me not understanding something in ES6 or React itself, but I feel there must be a way to pass arguments to a component like that - correct?

I've been reading the documentation but it's not quite clear.

Comment: They key different here are the destructured props in the stateless component. In a state component, props are passed into the constructor function

Comment: Oh got it, so I should be able to access these variables from this.props then? Or do I need to do something with the constructor

Comment: Sterling is right, and to add to his comment, the props are accessible with `this.props`.

Comment: Define your constructor as `constructor(props) { super(props); }`. Check out [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) for a more in depth explanation

Comment: @SterlingArcher The constructor is optional if you're not going to add anything else to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class components you have the props inside `this`, so you can access them anywhere inside the class by using `this.props` like so.

```js
const {keycloak, keycloakInitialized} = this.props;

// or simply
console.log(this.props.keycloak);
```

and you should take a look at this to understand [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Answer (score 1):

so this is destructoring from the props object. To achieve the same result inside of a class component write this inside your render function.

```
render() {
const {keycloak, keycloakInitialized} = this.props

return(<div></div>)

}
```

Comment: make sure that you declare your props inside of your constructor as well.. like this. constructor(props){super(props)}

Comment: The constructor is optional if you're not going to add anything else to it.

Comment: the constructor isn't optional when you have to access this.props?

Comment: It is. `constructor(props){ super(props); }` is the equivalent of the default constructor, you do not have to add it yourself unless you want to override it.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me on typescript (replace string for keyclock type):

```js
interface Props {
  keyclock: string;
  keyclockInitialized: boolean;
}

class LoginPage extends React.Component<Props> {

  keyclock:string
  keyclockInitialized:boolean

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.keyclock = props.keyclock;
    this.keyclockInitialized = props.keyclockInitialized
  }
  //...
```